# Change classes to an element with react

Tags: reactjs

I'd like to do something like Angular does with ng-class. I'm using react-tabs library (https://github.com/mzabriskie/react-tabs) and now I want to be able to change the background of the selected tab.
The library comes with a default effect for the selected tab but I want personalize it.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

if you're using an es6 transpiler you can use template strings and a ternary:

```
className={`base-class ${this.props.isActive? 'is-active' : ''}`}
```

Answer (score 3):

This works:

```
<div className={this.props.canChange ? "change-button" : "change-button gray-out"}>
blah
</div>
```

Basically classname is a property of the node.

Answer (score 1):

Just wrap your `<Tabs>` element with an element of your own `<div className="my-tabs">` and go from there! You can use the `aria-selected` to style the selected state.

Answer (score 0):

Other option is using ternary with Array join, check:

```
<my-element
  className={[
    'default-class',
    isClass1 ? 'class-1' : '',
    isClass2 ? 'class-2' : '',
    isClassN ? 'class-n' : ''
  ].join(' ')}
/>
```

In this way you can avoid concating strings and manage multiple classes at the same time :)